# How to remove specific characters in notepad++ with regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, programmers-notepad

This is data present in my .txt file

```
+919000009998    SMS    +919888888888
+919000009998    MMS    +91988 88888 88
+919000009998    MMS   abcd google
+919000009998    MMS    amazon
```

I want to convert my .txt like this

```
919000009998    SMS    919888888888
919000009998    MMS    919888888888
919000009998    MMS   abcd google
919000009998    MMS    amazon
```

removing the + symbol, and  also the spaces if present in third column only if it is a number, if it is string no operation to be performed

is there any regex to do this which can I write in search and replace in notepad++?

Answer (score -1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\+|(?<=\d)\h+(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  \+            # + sign
|               # OR
  (?<=\d)       # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before
  \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  (?=\d)        # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: this doesn't work for ```+919000009998    MMS    amazon+google```

Comment: @GuillaumeD: Where have you seen such string in the question?

Comment: @GuillaumeD, Toto could also tell you about some random not-specified-by-OP string that your regex does not work with. Should you get downvoted for that?

Comment: "if it is string no operation to be performed"

Comment: @GuillaumeD: They talk about spaces, not `+`

Comment: your interpretation

Comment: @GuillaumeD: Sure, not worst than yours! Ask the OP.

Comment: its a new account, sure he won't bother to come back. Anyway, I don't bother those two -non justified- downvotes. Chill out.

Comment: if you manage do it in one line without modifying ```+919000009998 MMS amazon+google```, I change my vote.  I'm fair.

Answer (score -1):

All previous answer will perfectly work.

However, I'm just adding this just in case you need it:

If for some reason you had non-phone numbers on the third column separated by spaces (a street comes to mind for me `+919000009998    MMS    street foo nº 123 4º-B`) you may use this regex instead (It will join number as long as the third column starts by `+`):

Search: `^[+](\S+\s+\S+\s++)(?:([^+][^\n]*)|[+])|\G\s*(\d+)`

Replace by: `\1\2\3`

That will avoid joining the `3` and `4` on my previous example.

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/KhF7pG/3/).

Comment: does n't work for ```+919000009998    SMS    9 198 88888888```

Comment: @GuillaumeD, as I stated on my answer, It is designed to work like that (It will join numbers as long as the third column starts by `+`)